# Using Turbolinks with unique JS for each page

Tags: javascript, webpack, turbolinks

I'm using Turbolinks on my website. My website has many pages where each page has a unique JS file **in addition** to the "base" js file.

Every page has the following scripts in its head:

```html
<head>
 ...
  <script defer src="/js/manifest.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
  <script defer src="/js/vendor.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
  <script defer src="js/app.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
...
</head>
```

Every page may include another JS file in its body:

```html
<body>
  ...
  <script src="/js/pages/page1/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Now many pages may load **the same** js file in their body tag:

### Page1:

```html
<body>
  ...
  <script src="/js/pages/page1/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

### Page 2:

```html
<body>
  ...
  <script src="/js/pages/page1/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

### Page 3:

```html
<body>
  ...
  <script src="/js/pages/page3/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Note how `Page 1` and `Page 2` load the same js file.

In order to build those JS files I use [Laravel Mix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix) which uses Webpack to compile and bundle the JS files.

When navigating between pages, since the JS file is embedded in the `<body>` element, the JS file is being re-downloaded (from cache) and re-evaluated by the browser. One would expect that if `page1/index.js` content is: `console.log('hey');`, they would see `hey` printed in their console for every page that loads the `page1/index.js` page.

However, unfortunately it is not the case. It seems like the browser does re-downloads the JS file, but for some reason, its content is not being executed. I believe this is due to the transpiled file's content. Because we are using Webpack to bundle the files, the file's content always starts with the following script:

```js
(window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[]).push(...
```

It looks like Webpack is managing the runtime scripts on its own in order to keep track of dependencies (and also "lazy" dependencies). Inspecting the `window.webpackJsonp` variable does indeed reveals 2 entries for the `pages1/index.js` file (the first entry is when the page was first loaded, the second one is when we navigated to another page that loaded that same file).

For some reason, Webpack decides not to re-run the script on subsequent page visits (using Turbolinks) which breaks the application.

Any ideas about what I can do in order to solve this are highly appreciated!